# mobileEmulation capabilities for Firefox in webdriver IO

Tags: webdriver, webdriver-io, selenium-firefoxdriver, wdio-v5

I am trying to write end to end test cases for mobile web browsers. So I am setting the configuration for google chrome as below and it runs fine.

```
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  'goog:chromeOptions': {
    mobileEmulation: { deviceName: 'Apple iPhone 6' },
  }
```

But I am not sure from where **'goog:chromeOptions'** is taken. I tried searching wdio docs and couldn't find any. 
I just got this from one of the blog that we need to pass key as **"goog:chromeOptions"**

Similarly I also need to run for Firefox and safari browsers. So I am not sure what key/hash we need to pass for firefox for mobile emulation.

I am trying to learn WDIO by practising simple exercises.

Comment: I'll respond to this after we finalize the other question you left open. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @rubyist. Did it help you? if so close the question (by accepting the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Set configuration for Google Chrome:

```
{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  'goog:chromeOptions': {}
}
```

Set configuration for the Firefox:

```
{
  browserName: 'firefox',
  'moz:firefoxOptions': {}
}
```

Set configuration for the Safari:

```
{
  browserName: 'safari',
  'safari.options': {}
}
```

Read more in the [CONFIGURATIONFILE.MD](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/dd4a37b74742267bb81b8f2e6065fed5aebc7746/docs/ConfigurationFile.md)